# Ways to recreate this karnaugh map in LaTeX

Tags: nicematrix

[image: karnaugh map]

I need to make karnaugh maps look like this in LaTeX. I tried, but didn't find a solution to my problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Where did you look? Did you try something? You tag your question with `nicematrix`, do you have something specific in mind?

Comment: I found NiceTabular environment in nicematrix package to be useful and tried to create karnaugh maps with this environment

Comment: HAve a look at these packages: 1) https://ctan.ebinger.cc/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-karnaugh/doc/tikz-karnaugh-doc.pdf, 2) https://ftp.rrze.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/karnaughmap/karnaughmap.pdf, 3)https://ctan.ebinger.cc/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/kvmap/kvmap.pdf, 4) https://ftp.rrzn.uni-hannover.de/pub/mirror/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/cartonaugh/cartonaugh.pdf, 5) https://ftp.agdsn.de/pub/mirrors/latex/dante/macros/latex/contrib/askmaps/askmaps.pdf

Comment: Please show us what you have so far, to give us something to start from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, you should first show what you tried so far, because this makes it easier to come up with answers that suit your needs. But since it is the second Sunday of Advent today, I feel generous. Maybe you could try something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\pgfset{
    nicematrix/cell-node/.append style={
        minimum size=2em,
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{ *{6}{c} }[create-medium-nodes]
\Block[draw]{2-2}{\diagbox
    {\scriptsize $Q_3(t)$ \\ $Q_2(t)$}
    {\scriptsize $Q_1(t)$ \\ $Q_0(t)$}} & & & & \\ 
 &    & 00 & 01 &     11 &     10 \\
 & 00 &  1 &    &        &        \\ 
 & 01 &    &  1 &        &      1 \\ 
 & 11 &    &  1 & $\ast$ & $\ast$ \\ 
 & 10 &    &  1 &        &      1 \\ 
\CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        round fit/.style 2 args={
            name suffix=-medium,
            draw, 
            rounded corners, 
            fit={#1}, 
            inner sep={-4pt+#2}
        }
    ]
        \draw (2-|3) -- (2-|7) -- (7-|7) -- (7-|2) -- (3-|2)
            (3-|3) -- (3-|7)
            (4-|2) -- (4-|7)
            (5-|2) -- (5-|7)
            (6-|2) -- (6-|7)
            (3-|3) -- (7-|3)
            (2-|4) -- (7-|4)
            (2-|5) -- (7-|5)
            (2-|6) -- (7-|6);
        \node[round fit={(3-3)}{0pt}] {};
        \node[round fit={(4-4) (5-4)}{0pt}] {};
        \node[round fit={(5-4) (6-4)}{2pt}] {};
        \node[round fit={(4-6) (5-6)}{0pt}] {};
        \node[round fit={(5-6) (6-6)}{2pt}] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's what I needed, thank you so much. I haven't got much experience in latex and use it only for a month. For me it is a really hard thing to pull off